# Sort model by id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I sideload `products` of a given `category`. The problem is that they are not sorted. I'd like to sort them by `id` and render the sorted `products` in a `select`.

*How can I sort them?*

**app/category/model.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  products: DS.hasMany('product', { async: true })
});
```

**route.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      category: this.store.find('category', 1)
    };
  }
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
{{view "select" prompt="All products"
       content=model.category.products
       optionLabelPath="content.name"
       optionValuePath="content.name"
       value=selectedProduct
       class="form-control"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed property and the [Ember.SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) to sort the products in your controller:

```
sortedProducts: Ember.computed('model.category.products', function() {
  return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['id'],
    sortAscending: true,
    content: this.get('model.category.products')
  });
})
```

And then simply use `sortedProducts` instead of `model.category.products`.

[**Source**](http://blog.yanted.com/2015/03/17/ember-js-quick-tip-3-sorting-array-ember-way/)

Comment: Should I add a `.property('model.destinationcategory.destinations')` to this?

Comment: Nope if you want to add it use the new syntax `computed('model.category.products', 'model.destinationcategory.destinations', function...`